# Using pdf vs using cdf to derive distribution of function of RV

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, change-of-variable

I come across the following question:

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution
with density $f(x; β) = \frac{\beta}{(1+x)^{\beta+1}}$ when $x > 0$ and zero elsewhere. The parameter $β > 0$
is an unknown parameter.

Show that $Y_i=\log(1+X_i) \sim EXP(1/\beta)$

So I did the following:

$$f(Y_i=y)=f(\log(1+X_i)=y)=f(1+X_i=e^y)=f(X_i=e^y-1)=\frac{\beta}{e^{y(\beta+1)}}=\frac{1}{(1/\beta)}e^{\frac{-y}{1/(\beta+1)}} \neq \frac{1}{(1/\beta)}e^{\frac{-y}{1/\beta}}$$

So I do not find the pdf of $EXP(1/\beta)$, which is the last expression.

Now apparently the method you should use is first find the cdf of $X_i$ from its pdf and *then* apply the above method, like so:

$$F(y)=P(Y_i \leq y)=P(X_i \leq e^y-1)=\int^{e^y-1}_{0}f(x)dx=...=1-e^{\frac{-y}{1/\beta}}$$

Which is the cdf of $EXP(1/\beta)$. So this method indeed finds the right answer. My question is: why is the first method (that I used) invalid?

Comment: What do you mean with $f(Y_i=y)$? That is peculiar notation that looks like $P(Y_i=y)$. It seems that you are confusing PDF and PMF and $X_i$ and $Y_i$ do not have a PMF. Both are continous random variables. Do not think that $P(Y_i=y)=f_{Y_i}(y)$ here because $P(Y_i=y)=0$ for every $y$.

Comment: With $f(Y_i=y)$ I mean the value of the probability density function of $Y_i$ if $Y_i=y$

Comment: It is not true in general that $f_{h(X)}=f_X\circ h^{-1}$. It is quite well possible that the RHS is not even a PDF.

Comment: See change of variables here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar.

Answer (score 1):

The first method is not valid because there is a confusion about the meaning of the pdf. An expression such as $f(Y_i=y)$ is meaningless. You could do a valid heuristic reasoning with infinitesimal quantities such as
\begin{equation}
f(y) d y \approx P(Y_i \in [y, y+d y]) = P(X_i \in [e^y-1, e^{y+dy}-1])
\approx P(X_i \in [e^y-1, e^y-1+e^y d y])
= \frac{\beta}{(e^y-1+1)^{\beta+1}} e^y d y
\end{equation}
And then one finds the correct result. Now some people could question the mathematical rigor of this reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

In the first method you forgot to multiply your density for $|\frac{dx}{dy}|=e^y$

You found

$f_Y(y)=\beta e^{-y\beta-y}$

Multiplying it by the derivate above, you get

$f_Y(y)=\beta e^{-y\beta}$

that, for $y \geq 0$ is the requested density

This is the ***Fundamental Transformation Theorem***; in poor words, itis the same issue of the variable change in an integral